# sudo: rvm: command not found - RVM MultiUser install on Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rvm, passenger

I'm setting up a server, it's an Ubuntu 12.04

first I installed RVM multi-user:

`me@ubuntu$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable`

then after RVM installed, as the installation suggests I added myself to RVM group

`usermod -a -G me rvm`

installed ruby
`rvm insall 1.9.3 --default`

then I tried to install system wide gem passenger and I get this:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ rvmsudo gem install passenger
sudo: gem: command not found
```

In fact any command run with `rvmsudo` just says `sudo : {command}: not found`

I need gems to be installed system wide, because it's a production server setup, also installing `passenger-install-nginx-module` requires root permissions as it installs int to `/opt/nginx/`

any thoughts?

Comment: Is this also possible without `usermod`?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1329) bug affects you.
Instead of waiting for a fixed release you might install an older version of rvm:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s -- --version 1.16.20
```

See https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ for details.

EDIT: This issue is now solved. `rvmsudo` is working for me (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: I was having this same problem today too. It's definitely the issue linked above, which is not fully fixed in rvm head (as of right now).

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem today too, and instead of waiting for the fix or installing an older version of rvm, I patched my rvmsudo file back to 1.16.x and left the rest of rvm alone.

first double check where rvmsudo is located on your system:

```
> which rvmsudo
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvmsudo
```

then replace it with the version from 1.16.x

```
curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/eef67d80409ee3291de83ec4f070bed5aaca6d41/binscripts/rvmsudo > /path/to/rvmsudo
```

Note: I actually tried first updating to the latest version of rvm, since the issue [that @trobter links to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817277/4575793) above in rvm's github account is marked as fixed, but the fix doesn't fully resolve the issue, so then I searched through their github account for the version of rvmsudo from 1.16.x, which did work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be because you did not add yourself to the rvm group. You said:

```
usermod -a -G me rvm
```

What it *should* be is:

```
usermod -a -G rvm me
```

In addition, I needed to add the following line to the end of my `.bashrc`:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

After that, just log into your shell again.

Answer (score 0):

Give rvmsudo the full path to your gem command?

Comment: This is more like a workaround, I want to know why is it doing that, and how to make it work without full paths?

Comment: Because rvmsudo sanitises your environment to avoid problems. If you still want to make it work, you can try "env PATH=$PATH_TO_GEM rvmsudo gem install foo" and see what happens?