# RVM Install on Linux Mint error (23) - Permissions Issue?

Tags: bash, rvm, linux-mint

I am trying to install ruby with RVM on Linux Mint and getting all sort of problems. Mainly:

```
{14:20}={bit@pimpinix:~}=> rvm install 2.4.1
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: __function_on_stack: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
sudo: __rvm_remote_server_path_single: command not found
sudo: __rvm_remote_server_path_single: command not found
No binary rubies available for: mint/18.3/x86_64/ruby-2.4.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more 
information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for mint.
Requirements installation successful.
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1, this 
may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
ruby-2.4.1 - #downloading ruby-2.4.1, this may take a while depending 
on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:- 
   -:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.4.1.tar.bz2.part: 
Permission denied
  0 11.9M    0  2759    0     0   7343      0  0:28:32 --:--:--  
0:28:32  7337
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2759)
There was an error(23).
Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby- 
2.4.1.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:- 
   -:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.4.1.tar.bz2.part: 
 Permission denied
  0 11.9M    0 16149    0     0   9556      0  0:21:55  0:00:01  
0:21:54  9555
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16149)
There was an error(23).
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the 
installation.
```

This has been an issue on all the recent ubuntu-flavored linuxes I have installed... except this one is worse. Help, please!?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, I suspect something like this is being run:

```
sudo [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544939/sudo-rvm-command-not-found-rvm-multiuser-install-on-ubuntu-12-04-server) .

You can't run `sudo [[` because sudo is not bash. Whereas bash can interpret the conditional syntax, sudo is expecting a command. However, it is possible to run `sudo bash -c "[[ -s '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm' ]] && source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'"`, so that bash takes care of the bashisms, and sudo has a command to run. Note that in this specific case, using `bash -c` as a wrapper may not do what you want, depending on what `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` is doing. So you may need to find another workaround.

I would try to figure out where the `sudo [[` is taking place, and make the changes I described.